# Query in finding unique array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I find script to get unique array in js. when i use if condition under filter function the return is not giving the correct result but when i simply return data the result is correct. Can anyone explain me why under if condition check result is wrong?

```
var x= ["apple","orange","banana","apple","mango"];
//var y= x.indexOf('apple');
//alert(y);

function checkdup(x)
{   
    let uniquearr= x.filter(function(val,index,arr){
    //return index== arr.indexOf(val); // return working correctly
    if(arr.indexOf(val)==index)
       {  return index; }   // showing wrong result why

    });
    //return uniquearr;
    console.log(uniquearr);
}

checkdup(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from `filter` is cast to `true` or `false` when deciding whether to keep an element in the returned array or not. When you're doing

`return index== arr.indexOf(val);`

you're returning a boolean - you're testing whether this element is the first occurrence of that element in the array. That's good, that's what you want. But when you

`return index;`

that is *always* true, except when `index` is 0 - which definitely isn't accomplishing what you want.